# How to change the default HTTP OPTIONS parameters in Java

Tags: java, http, http-headers

My java snippet looks like:

```
...
String type = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";
URL url = new URL("http://xxx/");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("OPTIONS");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", type);
...
```

When I sniff what this sends it sends a

OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1

which appears to be the default.

However, I actually want to send

OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with "plain" `java.net.URLConnection`. Consider replacing by [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x) which is less bloated and more configureable. You can force HTTP 1.0 mode by setting `http.protocol.version` to [`HttpVersion.HTTP_1_0`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpVersion.html#HTTP_1_0) in [`HttpClient#getParams()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpClient.html#getParams%28%29). You can find an example in [this document](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/preference-api.html).

Comment: OK - thanks - does the Apache client support the "*" parameter and how would I add it?

Comment: It's actually the request URI. I haven't used this particular method, so don't pinpoint me on it, but there's a `OptionsMethod` class taking an `URI`. You could pass `*` to it: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/OptionsMethod.html#OptionsMethod%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: On HttpClient 4.0 there's no OptionsMethod, it's rather HttpOptions class (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpOptions.html)

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: That's another (newer) API :) Click at the link I provided in my comment. A good hint though, upgrading to HttpClient 4.0.

Comment: I know, on Apache sites, they've mentioned that we should rather use HttpClient 4.0 or higher since they've made it more flexible that it's previous releases. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answer the following is the code using HTTPClient

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_0);
```

Hope it helps some one..